# Asynchronous Callback in GWT - why final?

Tags: asynchronous, event-handling, final, gwt-rpc

I am developing an application in GWT as my Bachelor's Thesis and I am fairly new to this. I have researched asynchronous callbacks on the internet. What I want to do is this: I want to handle the login of a user and display different data if they are an admin or a plain user.

My call looks like this:

```
serverCall.isAdmin(new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            //display error
        }

        public void onSuccess(Boolean admin) {
            if (!admin){
                //do something 
            }
            else{
                //do something else
            }

        }
    });
```

Now, the code examples I have seen handle the data in the //do something// part directly. We discussed this with the person who is supervising me and I had the idea that I could fire an event upon success and when this event is fired load the page accordingly. Is this a good idea? Or should I stick with loading everything in the inner function? What confuses me about async callbacks is the fact that I can only use final variables inside the onSuccess function so I would rather not handle things in there - insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the inner-class/ anonymous function it is generated at runtime it needs a static memory reference to the variables it accesses. Putting final to a variable makes its memory address static, putting it to a safe memory region. The same happens if you reference a class field.

Answer (score 1):

Its just standard java why you can only use Final variables inside an inner-class.  [Here is a great discussion discussing this topic](http://techtracer.com/2008/04/14/mystery-of-accessibility-in-local-inner-classes/).

When I use the AsyncCallback I do exactly what you suggested, I fire an event though GWT's EventBus.  This allows several different parts of my application to respond when a user does log in.